# Using 1:n relations in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, relation

I want to build a questionary in Django and use django's admin-interface to enter the data.
The site-admin should be able to set-up new questionaries with questions. Define models which questions have always a querstionary in relation is no problem:

```
class Questionary(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    questionary = models.ForeignKey(Questionary)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

Using this I can create and edit questionaries (but only it's title) in the admin. Also I can edit every single Question with an relation to the questionary. But only one question a time.

Is there a way to set up the models (or a part of the admin-area) to have the "questionary-part" at the top and the questions below that in the admin-interface? With buttons to add and delete questions?

Thanks a lot,

mfapl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, take a look at [InlineModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)